# How do I accept answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

How do I accept an answer for questions that I've asked?

Answer (score 5):

[image: Pic]