# How do I accept an answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I have an accept rate of 0, but I don't see any button in my view of Stack Overflow that would allow me to accept an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a 'check' thing (like a v) next to the answers which you can click on. When it turns green it means you accepted that answer.

Quoting this from [jjnguy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/2598/jjnguy) from another, similar [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73465/361484):

> [image: how to accept]

Answer (score 1):

To the left of each answer, there should be a *large outline of a check symbol*.  Logged in as the person who posted the question, you can click on that check, and it will turn green. That indicates that you have accepted the answer to which the check mark pertains.

Clicking on another transparent check will undo your previous acceptance and reassign it.